# facebook facepile connect shows two different messages

Tags: facebook, api, facepile

i have implemented facebook facepile via XFBML on two pages. one is home page and other is signup page.

Both pages have same code on it. (using include function, so im 100% its same code) even the XFBML code is same (using include function)

if i open up home page, it shows me

> Be the first of your friends to like this.

and if i open the sign up page, it shows me

> Basit is using Stackoverflow

does anyone have any idea why its doing this?

i been trying anything to fix it, but its not working..  cant find any solution online eaither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use `data-href="url_of_the_page"` in `<div class="fb-facepile" data-max-rows="6" data-width="292"></div>`